# Жестокая боль: сочетаемость

Tags: грамотная-речь, прилагательные, лексическая-сочетаемость, паронимы

> ЖЕСТОКАЯ, почти невыносимая боль пронзила его тело.

Разве боль может быть *жестокой*? Если да, то почему на современный слух словосочетание звучит диссонансно?

Comment: Часть населения, включая журналистов и дикторов, много чего и как говорит, иногда в каких-то штампах упорно повторяясь, но это не всегда складно или нормативно.

Comment: @Niemand разбивая ваш риторический вопрос: я сказал, что звучит диссонансно (=нескладно).

Comment: @Alex_ander да, вот я и пытаюсь понять, что делать с этим сочетанием.

Comment: Я только что ответ сочинил :)

Answer (score 3):

В толковом словаре Кузнецова:
**ЖЕСТО́КИЙ**, -ая, -ое; -то́к, -а́ и -а, -о; жесточа́йший, -ая, -ее.
2. Очень сильный, выходящий за пределы обычного. *Жестокий шторм. Жестокая битва. Жесточайшая засуха. Жестокое сопротивление. **Жестокая головная боль.** Жестокий спор*. // Резкий, очень сильный (о морозе, ветре и т. п.). Жестокий мороз. От жестокого ветра обмерзают лица.

Прилагательное *жестокий* означает сильную степень чего-то неприятного, доставляющего неудобство, огорчение.
Словосочетание *жестокая боль* представлено в словаре [русской идиоматики](https://idiomatika.academic.ru/237/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C) (сочетания слов со значением высокой степени), [в словаре эпитетов](http://www.slovopedia.com/24/193/1648014.html) — тоже присутствует (**боль**: о силе, интенсивности).

*Все его попытки разглядеть в них хоть что-то хорошее разбились, будто сброшенные с высокой башни, когда эти мерзавцы посмели нанести ему **жестокую боль**, убив верного друга* (О. Яковлев. Маски Черного Арлекина. 2011).

У В. Набокова ("Невеста рыцаря") и нежность может быть жестокой:
*Ты нежен был, — а нежность так жестока!

Одна, горю в вечерней вышине.

В блистанье битв, у белых стен Востока,

Таишь любовь учтивую ко мне.*

Мне думается, что нет на сегодня диссонанса: словосочетание использовалось раньше, используется и сейчас.

[Предложения со словосочетанием «жестокая боль»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C)

Comment: Язык автора первой цитаты не выглядит образцовым: боль не "наносят" подобно удару, а _причиняют_.

Comment: Попытаюсь поспорить. У Ефремовой: наносить — III. Причинять (боль, обиду и т. п.). https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/191135/Наносить

Comment: У Ефремовой дан близкий по _смыслу_ глагол, но не предлагается употреблять его в приведённых сочетаниях ("причинить" обиду или боль - корректно).
В словаре глагольной сочетаемости эти слова не пересекаются. Для "наносить":
https://abstrnoun.academic.ru/2404/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C
Для "боль":  https://abstrnoun.academic.ru/175

Answer (score 2):

Жестокость - свойство, обычно приписываемое *внешнему* источнику несправедливых действий с плохими последствиями или самим действиям, совершаемых кем-то сознательно. Это оценка проявления чьей-то *воли*. Поэтому корректность употребления к боли эпитета "жестокая" должна зависеть от *контекста*, а не только от присутствия сочетания в словарях. Например, выражение "**почувствовал жестокую боль**" (вместо сильной) вызывает вопрос: в чём эта боль проявляла жестокость, в чём была её "злая воля"? Просто в том, что была сильной? Для этого есть простое слово. В интересах пущей образности можно, однако, допустить "*жестокая боль терзала его часами, не отпуская*", где условно боль очеловечивается, обретая волю, и становится источником терзаний - это "с её стороны" *жестоко* и несправедливо. В таком же субъективном смысле и "жестокий мороз" может отмораживать носы или ещё чем-то досаждать персонажам, но простое сообщение "**стоял жестокий мороз**" воспринимается странно, в нём тоже можно почувствовать тот самый *диссонанс* как проявление небезупречности стиля.